# Bootstrap scoreboard page layout

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid black;">
  
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="text-left">
         <div class="text-center">
           <h1>54</h1>
           <h1> Team1 </h1> 
         </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class ="text-center">
       <h1>Game Day</h1>
      </div> 
    </div>
      <div class ="col-md-4">
        <div class="text-right">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h1> 56 </h1> 
            <h1> Team6 <h1> 
              </div>
            </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

[image]

I am trying to design a scoreboard using  bootstrap and struggling to get the things to lined up properly. Is it possible to do this in bootstrap?  I placed the image of what i am trying to do.

Comment: just a side note, i'd use CSS-Grid for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>



<div class="container" style="border:1px solid black;">

<div class = "row"> 
<div class = "col-lg-2"> <h1>54           </h1></div>
<div class = "col-lg-8" style=" text-align: center;"><h1>Game Day</h1> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-2"> <h1>56</h1></div>

</div>

<div class = "row"> 
<div class = "col-lg-2"> <h1>Team1           </h1></div>
<div class = "col-lg-8"><h1>      </h1> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-2"> <h1>Team6</h1></div>

</div>

</div>

<div class = "container">
<div class = "row"> 
<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-2"> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;"> Team 1 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;">  Team 2 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;"> Team 3 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-4"> </div>

</div>

<div class = "row"> 
<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-2" style=" text-align: center;" > <h4 class="text-success"> Score </h4> </div>
<div  class = "col-lg-1 " style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 54 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 15</div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 34</div>
<div class = "col-lg-4"> </div>
</div>


<div class = "row"> 
<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-2" style=" text-align: center; "> <h4 class="text-success"> Goal </h4> </div>
<div  class = "col-lg-1 " style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 70 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 70</div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 70</div>
<div class = "col-lg-4"> </div>
</div>



<div class = "row"> 
<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-2"> <h1>           </h1></div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;"> Team 1 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;"> Team 2</div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;"> Team 3</div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;"> Team 4</div>
<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
</div>


<div class = "row"> 
<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-2" style=" text-align: center; "> <h4 class="text-success"> Score </h4> </div>
<div  class = "col-lg-1 " style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 52 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 26</div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 56</div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 36 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
</div>


<div class = "row"> 

<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
<div class = "col-lg-2" style=" text-align: center; "> <h4 class="text-success"> Goal </h4> </div>
<div  class = "col-lg-1 " style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 70 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 70</div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 70</div>
<div class = "col-lg-1" style=" text-align: center;  border:1px solid black; margin: 3px "> 70 </div>
<div class = "col-lg-3"> </div>
</div>

</div>    




<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try the above code, you have not included the bootstrap link to css in header section and bootstrap link to js in body section. The other part of score and goal rows should be easy now for you. give a try.